# Has anyone made their own capstones?

Tags: concrete

I saw this
https://youtu.be/5eLLuXZMDik

And tried to something similar except I'm not sure what to make the decorative part with.  In the video he uses quarter round.  My caps are to be on the top of a natural bluestone wall.  I tried Alexander moulding and a kind of flattened out quarter round.  Just doesn't seem to go quite right.

Has anyone made anything similar?

Comment: From a style point of view concrete and natural stone are not an easy mix.  The eye knows this right away.  If you have a stone wall put a natural stone cap on it.

Comment: It's hard to find a natural cap.  Given the varying width of bluestone it can be wider than most of the pieces.  I have seen some really nice manufactured capstones, but they are very expensive and usually just 12" wide

Comment: Where I live we have numerous choices that are called coping or steps. They come in machine cut or hammered faces and much of comes from the States.  See here https://cohenandcohen.com/product-category/natural-stone/steps-treads-copings/  Perhaps you could broaden your search for a supplier

Comment: Yeah that's an option.  Around here it's like the ep Henry to